# AngularJS service: gets error has no method 'save'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm using AngularJS v1.0.7 and here's how I setup the service:

```
angular.module('myAngularJSApp.services',['ngResource'])
    .factory('RegisterNumber', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource( '../api/register/number/:id', {id:'@id'});
    }])
    .factory('RegisterChannel', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource( '../api/register/channel/:id', {id:'@id'});
    }])
```

and here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myAngularJSApp')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'RegisterNumber', 'RegisterChannel', function ($scope, RegisterNumber, RegisterChannel) {

    $scope.step = 1;
    $scope.advanceStep = function(_step){
      var AcctNum = RegisterNumber
        , AcctChn = RegisterChannel

      switch(_step){
        case 1:
          var acctNum = AcctNum.save({ // This line throws the error
                          id : $scope.security_number 
                        },
                        // SUCCESS
                        function(){
                          $scope.showError = false;
                          advance(_step);
                        },
                        // ERROR
                        function(response){
                          $scope.showError = true;
                        });
          break;
        case 2:
          var acctChn = AcctChn.save(
                        { id : $scope.channel},
                        // SUCCESS
                        function(response){
                          $scope.showError = false;
                          advance(_step);
                        },
                        // ERROR
                        function(response){
                        });
          break;
      }
    }        
  }]);
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'
    at Object.$scope.advanceStep ...
```

I did some inspections: `console.log(AcctNum)` gives a `LocationHashbangUrl` object. However, strangely enough `console.log(AcctChn)` gives:

```
function Resource(value){
        copy(value || {}, this);
      }
```

which is correct. I have searched similar questions & tried the answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251181/angularjs-creating-a-service-object), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286713/angular-resource-update-method-not-found), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043532/angularjs-services-update-save)) but I keep getting the same error. Did I miss something? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have wrong injection:

```js
angular.module('myAngularJSApp')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', 
    [
               '$scope', '$location',    'RegisterNumber', 'RegisterChannel', 
      function ($scope,   RegisterNumber, RegisterChannel) { ... }
    ]
  );
```

You're missing `$location` param in controller function signature.

Comment: Oops! missed that one out. Thanks!

Comment: Can't we rewrite the controller definition as ; angular.module('myAngularJSApp')
  .controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope,   RegisterNumber, RegisterChannel) { ... }
    
  );

Comment: That way the app would break when minimised.