# Why angular doesn't apply method on the object?

Tags: angularjs

I defined a resource and form for creating new products. When user fill the form and click on a button, it calls controller method and then resource method for creating of new product.

Here is my implementation:

```
<form>
    <input ng-model="product.title" />
    <input ng-model="product.desc" />
    <input ng-model="product.price" />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" ng-click="add(product)"/>
</form>
```

*Product service*

```
function ProductService($resource) {
    return {
        // basic
        products: $resource('http://localhost/rest-api/products/:id', null, {
            create: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: false
            },
            read: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {
                    id: '@idProduct'
                },
                isArray: false
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                isArray: false
            }
        })

    };
}
```

*controller method*

```
$scope.add = function (product) {
    function success(data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }

    function error(e) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }

    product.$create().then(success, error);
}
```

But after click on submit button, it throws following error:

```
Error: product.$save is not a function
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" ng-click="add(product)"/>` Where is `product` defined?

Comment: I added input fields to form. `Product` is defined in form using directive `ng-model`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS service: gets error has no method 'save'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544556/angularjs-service-gets-error-has-no-method-save)